# PHP Imagemagick convert greyscale to RGB

Tags: php, imagemagick, color-profile

I made a tool where people can upload photos and modify them, including desaturation, resulting in a greyscale image.
I generate the final image using PHP's GD library.

When printing these images the colors appear wrong so using Image Magick I add a color profile.

This works great except for images that have been greyscaled. The color profile gets added, but when I open the image in Photoshop, it says "The embedded ICC profile cannot be used because the ICC profile is invalid. Ignoring the profile".
In Photoshop the image is set to Greyscale rather than RGB, hence the attached RGB profile is wrong. I need it to be RGB.

I'm using the following code to add all the possible information in an attempt to make the image RGB:

```
<?php
$i = new Imagick();
$i->readimage('image.jpg');
$i->setimagetype(Imagick::IMGTYPE_TRUECOLOR);
$i->setimagecolorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
$i->profileimage('icc', file_get_contents('AdobeRGB1998.icc'));
$i->writeimage($d);
$i->destroy();
?>
```

Does anyone know how to successfully set the image to RGB and attach the profile?

I did try the different methods and combinations for 'setImageProfile' and 'profileImage', also for colorspace and imagetype, but the result is always the same.

Comment: You are reading in a file. Are you sure it does not contain a profile, that, with your profile added, will result in that what adobe photoshop makes telling about an invalid profile? And do you know what specifically the notice by your copy of adobe photoshop means?

Comment: The file created with GD is (always) without any color profile. I think the notice in PS means, that I attached a profile meant for colors, which is not suitable for greyscale images. Photoshop sees the image as greyscale by default, even without a color profile attached. Also, when the image is in greyscale mode, in PS I can only attach color profiles named 'Dot gain 10%', '20%' etc. If I change the image to RGB, I can attached the color profile I need. Somehow I must let PS know it is an RGB image with only grey pixels in it or something like that.

Comment: The I'd say reading the image set's the wrong imagetype. You might need to create a new image and add an image from a file. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Do you mean creatign a blank image, set all properties and add the image that I actually want to modify? I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yes I mean that. Also check options when writing a file.

Comment: I didn't have any time to put into this, bu tI manage to fix this by 'cheating' the image. I took 1 pixel and added a tiny bit more color to it. I'll edit the code in my original post.

Comment: @ar34z: FYI, if you found a solution, it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question and accept your own answer.

Comment: Thank you, Leigh. I've done it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me to have it recognized as a truecolor image. Assuming `$img` is the Imagick object containing the greyscaled image, I check if it is indeed greyscale and then edit 1 random pixel and modify its red value by adding or substracting 5 values, depending on red being greater than 5 or not.

```
<?php
if ($img->getImageType() == Imagick::IMGTYPE_GRAYSCALE)
{
    // Get the image dimensions
    $dim = $img->getimagegeometry();

    // Pick a random pixel
    $x = rand(0, $dim['width']-1);
    $y = rand(0, $dim['height']-1);

    // Define our marge
    $marge = 5;
    //$x = 0;
    //$y = 0;

    // Debug info
    echo "\r\nTransform greyscale to true color\r\n";
    echo "Pixel [$x,$y]\n";

    // Get the pixel from the image and get its color value
    $pixel = $img->getimagepixelcolor($x, $x);
    $color = $pixel->getcolor();
    array_pop($color); // remove alpha value

    // Determine old color for debug
    $oldColor   = 'rgb(' . implode(',',$color) . ')';
    // Set new red value
    $color['r'] = $color['r'] >= $marge ? $color['r']-$marge : $color['r'] + $marge;
    // Build new color string
    $newColor   = 'rgb(' . implode(',',$color) . ')';

    // Set the pixel's new color value
    $pixel->setcolor($newColor);

    echo "$oldColor -> $newColor\r\n\r\n";

    // Draw the pixel on the image using an ImagickDraw object on the given coordinates
    $draw = new ImagickDraw();
    $draw->setfillcolor($pixel);
    $draw->point($x, $y);
    $img->drawimage($draw);

    // Done, 
    unset($draw, $pixel);
}
// Do other stuff with $img here
?>
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

@a34z says in a comment:

> *"Somehow I must let PS know it is an RGB image with only grey pixels in it or something like that."*

**It is a fundamental error to assume that an RGB image could even contain 'gray' pixels as such!**

RGB images do have pixels that are always composed of a mix of 3 *colors*: **R** ed + **G** reen + **B** lue. These are the 3 channels which are available, no more. There is no such thing as a gray channel in RGB.

What makes an RGB image **look** gray to our eyes is the fact that each of the 3 numerical channel values are equal or less strictly speaking, at least 'similar enough'. Of course, there is also software that can analyze the color values of the 3 channels and tell you which pixels are 'gray'. ImageMagick's histogram output would happily tell you which shades of gray you would say and use different names for those Grays. But don't be fooled by that color name: the pixel will still be composed from 3 colors with the same (or very similar) intensities, and ImageMagick will also report these values.

If you really need a pure grayscale image (that uses only one channel for the level of gray, not three), then you have to convert it to such an image type.

The two images may still look the same (if the conversion was done correctly, and if your monitor is calibrated, and if your not red-green-blind) -- but their internal file structure is different.

RGB images need ICC profiles that deal with RGB (if any), such as sRGB. For grayscale you cannot use sRGB, there you may want to use DeviceGray or something...

Comment: Yes, I know the image still consists of RGB channels, but I can't help that Photoshop sees it as a greyscale image and says the attached color profile is invalid.